# How can I search a customer by full name?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm creating a method wherein a user can search a customer either by first name, last name, or full name. the search bar only shows the result if it's by first or last name but when I try searching a customer by full name the record won't show.

Here's my code:

```
public int getMatchingCustomerRecords(String keyword) {
    int rows = 0;
    try {
        if (db.startTransaction()) {
            String sql = "Select COUNT(firstName OR lastName) AS TOTAL FROM Customer";
            String sqlSearch = "";
            if (keyword != null) {
                sqlSearch = sql + " WHERE firstName LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' AND lastName LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
                ps = db.getQueryStatement(sqlSearch);
            } else {
                ps = db.getQueryStatement(sql);
            }

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                rows = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Should it be `OR lastName...`?

Comment: You don't query any record, you only receive the count. Is that desired? You are using the `keyword` in the query for first name and last name, that means you will only get records where first name and last name contain this `keyword` (means: you will get Mr. Smithy Smith but not Mr. Sminty Smith).

Comment: It goes without saying that this code will leave you wide open to an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 2):

Your queries should be:

```
Select * FROM `Customer`
WHERE `firstName` LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR `lastName` LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getMatchingCustomerRecords(String keyword) {
        int rows = 0;
        try {
            if (db.startTransaction()) {
                String sql = "Select COUNT(firstName OR lastName) AS TOTAL FROM Customer";
                String sqlSearch = "";
                if (keyword != null) {

             String[] keywordArray=keyword.split(" ");


            if(keywordArray.length>1) {
             // matching full Name
                sqlSearch = sql+" WHERE firstName LIKE '%" + keywordArray[0].trim() + "%' AND lastName LIKE '%" + keywordArray[1].trim() + "%'";
            }else {
             // matching firstName or lastName
                sqlSearch = sql+" WHERE firstName LIKE '%" + keywordArray[0].trim() + "%' OR lastName LIKE '%" + keywordArray[0].trim() + "%'";
            }
             ps = db.getQueryStatement(sqlSearch);
         } else {
             ps = db.getQueryStatement(sql);
         }
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    rows = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public int getMatchingCustomerRecords(String keyword) {
int rows = 0;
try {
    if (db.startTransaction()) {
        String sql = "Select COUNT(firstName OR lastName) AS TOTAL FROM Customer";
        String sqlSearch = "";
        if (keyword != null) {
            sqlSearch = sql + " WHERE LOCATE(firstName ,'" + keyword + "')>=0 AND LOCATE(lastName ,'" + keyword + "')>=0";
            ps = db.getQueryStatement(sqlSearch);
        } else {
            ps = db.getQueryStatement(sql);
        }

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            rows = rs.getInt("TOTAL");

        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return rows;
```

}

Comment: Please don't post code-dump answers as they're as bad as code-dump questions and will not likely help future visitors. At least explain your answer as well, and in fact more effort should be put into the explanation than the code. Please have a look at [answer] for more on best-practice when answering questions on this site.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually fix the problem either.